# GoogleCredential is deprecated in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-signin, deprecated

I have looked everywhere about a new implementation of the deprecated GoogleCredential  but nothing seems to work in my use case:

We are creating a flutter application as the client and Spring Boot application as the Rest API and we are used to send the access token retrieved from the client (package:google_sign_in) to the API to go throught this lines to get the profile information from google api:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Oauth2 oauth2 =
    new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
        .build();
Userinfo userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
```

but the issue is that GoogleCredential and JacksonFactory are now depricated.
thank you for your advice.